# $.ajax POST returning “status”:403,“statusText”:“interdit” cordova android

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, tomcat

I am developing Android cordova application with jquery.mobile and cordova
i am calling $ajax for web service. below is a code snippet.

```
$.ajax({
           "url": serverPath+"/taxiws/clients/saveclient",
           "type": "POST",
           contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
           "data": JSON.stringify(obj),
           "success": function(data) {
              alert("success!!! "+data);
               window.localStorage.setItem('client', JSON.stringify(obj));   
            $("#LoadingBackgroundPopup").hide();

            window.location.href="reservationclient.html";

},  "error":  function(error,jqXHR, textStatus){

     alert("erreur "+textStatus+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }
});
```

its responding with this error:

```
error{"readyState":4",responseText":"","status":403,"statusText":"Interdit"}
```

what is wrong this code ? why it is not working ? any help, suggestion will be appreciated

thank you in advance.

Comment: issue is from server side. 403 means Ajax request is forbidden.

Comment: the same web service in another server its work ,how i can resolve this error ?? please

Comment: Enable ajax requests in server. must be some restrictions added. remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your web service is whitelisted in the cordova configuration.

Read more about [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)